# Is it possible to make Ctrl+C as responsive as Ctrl+Break in the Windows 7 console?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, console

Is it possible to make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> act like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd> in the Windows 7 `cmd.exe` console?

By default <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> seems to only send a signal the next time the input buffer is read, where <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd> sends a signal immediately.

This makes <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> useless for ending processes because when I want to end a process I want to end it immediately.

I'm using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd> for now but it's far harder to type.

It looks like in DOS you can add `BREAK=ON` to `CONFIG.SYS` to achieve this, but not in Windows 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no setting that I know of, but you can accomplish this with an [AutoHotkey](http://autohotkey.com/) script.

#### The script

```
^c::
    WinGetClass, WinClass, A
    if(WinClass = "ConsoleWindowClass")
        SendPlay ^{CtrlBreak}
    else
        SendPlay ^c
```

#### How it works

- `^c` specifies the key combination to modify: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> (`^` indicates <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>).
- `WinGetClass, WinClass, A` stores the active window's title in the variable `WinClass`.
- `if(WinClass = "ConsoleWindowClass") ... else ...` checks if `WinClass` macthes the string `ConsoleWindowClass` (the window class of the Windows 7 command prompt).

  - If it does, `SendPlay ^{CtrlBreak}` simulates the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Break</kbd>.
  - Otherwise, `SendPlay ^c` simulates the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.

    This way, other programs still behave as they should.

#### How to use

1. [Download](http://www.autohotkey.com/download/) and install the latest version of AutoHotkey.
2. Save the above script as `break-on.ahk`, using your favorite text editor.
3. Double-click the file to run the script.
4. If you wish, copy the script (or a link to it) in the `Startup` folder.