# Keyboard shortcut for rotate in Lightroom on AZERTY keyboard

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, adobe-lightroom

I'm using a [Belgian AZERTY keyboard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout#Belgian) and have trouble finding how to execute the rotate image keyboard shortcut in Adobe Lightroom 4.

The shortcut for rotate right is `CTRL` + `]` but I find it impossible to execute it on my keyboard layout.

Hitting `ALT GR` + `$` inserts the `]` character but simultaneously holding `CTRL` doesn't do a thing in Lightroom.

Answer (score 1):

[AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) may help you? Bind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> to any combo, which is pressable on your keyboard.

Example for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> here: https://superuser.com/a/441571/139371